# SuiteScript Redirect Option on BeforeSubmit

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a beforeSubmit userEventScript that updates a Customer record. After the Customer record is updated, I would like to redirect the user to the addressbook (in edit mode) for cleansing. What are my options for redirecting (within this script), considering the following API's will not fire in a beforeSubmit event?

```
require(['N/url', 'N/record'], function(url, r) {
   var output = url.resolveRecord({
       recordType: r.Type.CUSTOMER,
       recordId: 6,
       isEditMode: true
   });
});



require(['N/redirect', 'N/record'], function(redirect, r) {
    redirect.toRecord({
        "type": r.Type.CUSTOMER,
        "id": 6,
        "isEditMode": true
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that for a reason. If you were able to redirect in the before submit then all your previous edits would be lost.

What you need to do is create a client script that changes to the address tab and returns false from saveRecord. Obviously you'd need to record whether you'd already forced an address check so that you could return true when everything is clean.